# Can't get simple regular expression to work in Google Sheets QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets `QUERY` function does not seem to use regular expressions.

I want to match strings with an arbitrary number of spaces before the string. My `QUERY` function is:

```
=QUERY('$A$1:$B$2, "select B where A=' *abc'")
```

It returns `#N/A`

It works when my data does not have the leading blanks and the match string is just 'abc'. It's acting as if sheets has regular expressions disabled.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try like this:

```
=QUERY(A1:B2, "select B where A contains 'abc'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The original question was about having a regular expression. This answer does not include a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

if you need something more strict try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "abc$")), , B1:B))
```

[image: 0]